# how to get the Image from Gallery and set into Image view in Fragments?

Tags: android

I have Written code for getting  the Image from gallery and set into the Image View but the image is not set.This is my problem suggest me guys

Here is My Code:

```
 btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
{
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);

            }
        });


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && null != data) 
{
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //int pic=Integer.parseInt(picturePath);
            cursor.close();

            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mFormView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ivMan.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: are you getting file path?

Comment: when I click on the Upload Button Gallery opens and I select the image from gallery ,but that selected image is not replace the old image

Answer (score 0):

1. for getting image from gallery

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setType("image/*");
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
   ```
2. Check if you have a proper  path if yes than decode the image and set to      imageview.

   ```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
       Uri _uri = data.getData();

       //User had pick an image.
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       //Link to the image
       final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
       cursor.close();
       File file = new File(imageFilePath);
       if (file.exists()) {
           Bitmap bMap = decodeFile(file);
           //  asset.setImageBitmap(bMap);
           asset.setImageBitmap(bMap);
       }
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   ```

   }

this will defiantly help you

Comment: we are selecting the image from gallery so the path will not  be the same to compare the two paths

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
 try to use this for getting image from gallery

Answer (score 0):

Replace getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1); with
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

Comment: I tried to print the path of the image but i cant get the path from toast also.